# One-to-one relations that only go one way in Laravel

Tags: laravel, entity-relationship, one-to-one, has-one, database-relations

Is it possible/right to have a a relation between tables that **only goes one way**? I have an `invoices` table that I need to reference in other tables likes `commission_payments` and `membership_payments` but the `invoices` table does not need a `commission_payment_id` or a `membership_payment_id`. In other words, there different types of transactions that can happen and they all may have a invoice attached, but the invoice does not need to reference these transaction tables.

```
invoices           commission_payments      membership_payments
---------------    ---------------------    ---------------------
-id                -id                      -id
...                -invoice_id              -invoice_id
                   ...                      ...
```

I have created Eloquent models for each table. I added a `hasOne` relation to `invoices` on the other two models.

```
class CommissionPayment extends Model{
    public function invoice(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Invoice');
    }
}
```

I then tried accessing the Comission Payment's attached invoice like this:

```
$com = CommissionPayment::first();
$com->invoice->id;
```

I then get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 
'invoices.commission_payment_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `invoices` 
where `invoices`.`commission_payment_id` = 15 and `invoices`.`commission_payment_id` is not
null limit 1)
```

Why is it looking for `commission_payment_id` field in the `invoices` table? I would expect a query sort of like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `invoices` WHERE `id` = 23 
/* id is fetched from the `invoice_id` field in the `commission_payments` table */
```

Do I HAVE to add a column for each table that will reference invoice_id? At the moment it's two but this could grow. Also, when an invoice was generated for a commission payment, it won't need the membership payment field so I don't think it should go there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A one-to-one relationship is setup using either the `hasOne` or `belongsTo` relationship. The `hasOne` side of the relationship assumes the foreign key is stored on the other table. The `belongsTo` side of the relationship has the foreign key.

Therefore, since your foreign key to the invoices are stored on the commission_payments and membership_payments tables, those models are said to belong to the invoices table.

Change your relationship from `hasOne` to `belongsTo` and you should be good to go:

```
class CommissionPayment extends Model{
    public function invoice() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Invoice');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation! This really helps!